# AngularJS - Displays html tags, how to make it readable

Tags: php, angularjs, json, angularjs-controller, ng-bind-html

i am using PHP as Modal, and Angularjs as Controller, and to display in front end, I am converting PHP into JSON. It displays like as below shown in Front End. I want to display a readable one with li tag and break tag and other texts only. I don't want any other html tags in front end. Please help.

Front End:

[image]

JSON Code:

[image]

PHP Code:

```
elseif (isset($_GET['product_id']) && $_GET['product_id'] == 'getProduct') {
    $data = array();

    while ($product = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $name = str_replace('&quot;', "", $product['product_name']);
        $description = str_replace('&quot;', "", $product['product_description']);
        $category_name = str_replace('&quot;', "", $product['category_name']);

        $pro = array('id' => $product['product_id'], 'name' => utf8_encode($name), 'description' => utf8_encode($description),
            'price' => utf8_encode($product['product_price']), 'weight' => $product['product_weight'], 'weight_class' => $product['product_weight_class'], 'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
            'link' => $product['product_image_url'], 'cat' => utf8_encode($category_name));
        array_push($data, $pro);

    }

    $product_encode = json_encode($data);
    //$product_encode = htmlspecialchars_decode($product_encode);
    //$product_encode = html_entity_decode($product_encode);

    echo strip_tags($product_encode);
}
```

Controller Angular:

```
   $http.get("https://example.com/store/www/api.php?product_id=getProduct")
                    .success(function (detail) {
                        $scope.details = detail;

                        var url = window.location.href;
//$scope.categoryId = '20';
                        var final = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/'));
                        $scope.productId = final.split("=")[1];


                        console.log($scope.details);
                    });
```

View:

[image]

Comment: Use the ng-bind-html directive instead of interpolation. ng-bind-html doesn't escape html entities <p ng-bind-html="product.description"><p>. You will need to include the angular-sanitize.js library in your project - as well as set a dependency on the ngSanitize module for this to work.

Comment: you can use ng-sanitize please check this for refrence https://embed.plnkr.co/X2g8jE/

Answer (score 0):

try using pre tag - you can test here - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9wfjafa/)

```
<pre> {{product.description}} </pre>
```

Comment: I am getting same output

Answer (score 0):

Use angular ng-sanitize to format html page on view. Refer below link for example. Tell me if it help you or not.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

Comment: a little more elaborate answers are expected than a straight reference!

Comment: I think no need to elaborate, that link will explain everything.

Comment: this would better be a comment! please have a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering).